# Using a Plugin to Show/Hide Content after Header?

Tags: plugins

Using a plugin,I am looking a way to Show/Hide all Content after Headers are sent. If I have an authenticated user then show the content other wise redirect the user to authenticate first.

I want to use Facebook PHP SDK to authenticate the user. My questions are

1. Using which Hook or Action I can put a check whether User is authenticated or Not.
2. If user is authenticated, continue with WordPress Loop to show Content else Redirect to Facebook for Authentication.

A rough pseudo code is

> After header 
>   if Facebook user
>   Continue WordPress Loop 
>   else Redirect

Comment: Do you want to check this before the page even loads up? Why do you want to redirect after headers are sent?

Comment: Headers are sent by Facebook SDK and also a check before <Head> blocks Facebook to crawl Open Graph tags. In short, it can be checked right after <Body> at sometime before content Loads

Comment: Aha... I get it. Then try using `loop_start` action. It runs before the loop begins.

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate the logic more? Suppose that i do this what would be the code to stop or continue the loop and also where would be the else check 

add_action('loop_start','myfunction')
then
function myfunction()
{if ($user) 
//How do I Continue Loop
else
//How Do I Stop Loop
}

Comment: Its an action, so you won't need to return anything. Just check if you're logged in, if not, then redirect to login / warning page, else continue.

Comment: @rutiwick Thanks. Sometimes a VISIBLE thing becomes invisible. That's what happened to me

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library located at [Github](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/readme.md).

```
    <?php

  require './facebook.php';

   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR APP ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR API SECRET',
'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));


 if ($facebook->getSession()) {
   PLACE YOUR WP LOOP HERE
} else {
   echo '<a href="' . $facebook->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
   ADD YOUR APP's 'Connect' button here.
}
    ?>
```

Include *facebook.php* from the library located at Github (2nd line).